# Why I can use the class name as a function name?

Tags: c++, class, identifier

As far as I know in `C++` we cannot use the same `identifier` for another declaration:

```
 int x;
 char x; // compile-time error: redefinition.
```

But here is an example where I was messing with `classes`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



class A {
    public:
        A(int);
        void print()const;
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, A& rhs);
    private:
        int value1;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, A& rhs) {
    out << "rhs.value1 = " << rhs.value1 << std::endl;
    return out;
}



A::A(int x) : value1(x) { std::cout << "ctor A(x)" << std::endl; }

void A::print()const {
    std::cout << "value1: " << value1 << std::endl;
}

int A(int x) {
    std::cout << "inside A(int x)" << std::endl;
    return x;
}



int main(){


    class A a { 0 };
    a = A(7);
    a.print();
    std::cout << A(7) << std::endl;

    std::cout << A(5) << std::endl; // here if I comment out the function a it is ok as long as I overloaded the insertion operator
    // and if I add the function A it hides the insertion operator!


    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see above I must add the keyword `class` whenever I declare an object of `class A`otherwise I get a compile-time error. Why?

- Is the expression `a = A(7);` a function call and the return value is passed to the constructor of `class A` that takes an integer. Or simply no function call but only `ctor` call?

Comment: `A a(0);` not working would be a most-vexing-parse issue; `A a{0}` should just work. Being able to use `class A` instead of just `A` is similar to being able to use `struct A` instead of `A`, which is at the very least necessary for compatibility with C

Comment: It is legal to have a class, an enum, and a thing that's neither a class nor an enum to have the same name; a sad legacy of C language. Such a name by itself is taken to refer to the "thing" when possible; one can use so-called elaborate type specifiers `class Name` and `enum Name` to name the class and the enum.

Comment: `a = A(7);` calls function `A`, then constructs a temporary of class `A` from the resulting `int`, and assigns it to `a` using the implicitly defined copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you have a class A and a function A, so you have to point out A is a class or a function that's why you have to add "class" when you declare an object of A.

According to the following code, two classes, A and B, are defined, they are exactly same, but A can be a function or a class, so when you declare a object A, you have to add a "class" before A, while declare a object of B is no need to add a "class"

For the second question, first function A is called, and its return value is used to construct object a. You can see first x=7 is in the function A, and ctor x=8 because the function return x+1.

The output:

```
ctor A(x) x=0
inside A(int x) x=7
ctor A(x) x=8
ctor B(x)
```

The test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A { 
    public:
       A(int);
    private:
        int value1;
};

class B { 
    public:
       B(int);
    private:
        int value1;
};

B::B(int x) : value1(x) { std::cout << "ctor B(x)" << std::endl; }

A::A(int x) : value1(x) { std::cout << "ctor A(x) x=" << x <<std::endl; }

int A(int x) {
    std::cout << "inside A(int x) x=" << x << std::endl;
    x=x+1;
    return x;
}   


int main(){
    class A a(0);
    a = A(7);

    B b(0);

    return 0;
}
```